# interact.js allowFrom not working for draggable handle outside draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, interact.js

I have this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/700857/

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable-element">
    test
</div>
<div class="handle">
    handle
</div>
```

JS:

```
interact('#draggable-element')
  .draggable({
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    allowFrom: '.handle',
    ignoreFrom: '#draggable-element'
  });


  function dragMoveListener() {
      alert('working')
  }
```

When it is like this, I cannot drag the element because the handle is outside the draggable element. As soon as I put the handle in the draggable element, I can drag it: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/700871/

Because of technical reasons and HTML altering I prefer to have my handles outside the draggable element.
Are there any ideas on how to fix this without altering the source code of interact.js?

Comment: is it not possible if use class instead of id?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by that? Or create a fiddle?